# Python for i in list

Tags: python

```
response = [0, 1, 2]
for i in response:
    response[i] = tags_re.sub('', response[i])
```

`"'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'"`

how to edit that list?

I need change all elements of list

Comment: Is that the actual list you want to fix?

Comment: what is the expected output? Are you intending to use the same variable (response) as the input, the index, and the output? That is unusual.

Comment: @hughdbrown: that's not the issue here. His sample code doesn't match the code that actually raises the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response = [0, 1, 2]
for i in range(len(response)):
    response[i] = tags_re.sub('', response[i])
```

or even better try a list comprehension

```
response = [...]
response_fixed = [tags_re.sub('',val) for val in response]
```

actually your value will be an integer which will cause problems when you call re.sub, so I am operating under the assumtion that response is actually a list of strings

Comment: What did you use for tags_re when you tested this code? This does not work: `import re; tags_re = re.compile("a")`

Answer (score 2):

The `for <var> in <collection>` iterates through the list, binding `<var>` to the element. It is *not* an index. (In your case, it may *act* as an index, but I don't know if you're just providing an example or not, so I'm going to answer for the general case.) In other words, in this snippet of code:

```
response = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i in response:
  print i
```

`i` would be `"one"`, `"two"`, and "`three`", in turn.

It sounds like you may want indices, not the actual value, in which case you should use `enumerate`:

```
response = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i, val in enumerate(response):
  response[i] = rotate_by_13(val)
```

If you want to apply a function to every element of a list, you can also use a list comprehension:

```
response = ["one", "two", "three"]
response = [rotate_by_13(e) for e in response]
```

Or the `map` function:

```
response = ["one", "two", "three"]
response = map(lambda e: rotate_by_13(e), response)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your list is actually in the form `["1", "2", "3"]`. Change your call to `response[i]` to `response[int(i)]` to convert the strings to integers.

If that isn't the format of your list, you can instead do something like this [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
response = [tags_re.sub(my_magic_regex, elem) for elem in response]
```

That will replace response with a new list, where each element is the old element after being run through whatever `tags_re.sub()` does. Note that this assumes the elements of your list can be used by `sub()` (either deliberately converted to strings with `str(elem)` or that they are strings already).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you never really want to edit a list while iterating through it. You're gonna have a bad time. (More-so with adding and removing entries, but its just good practice.)

You want something like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = []

for i in list1:
    temporaryVariable = doSomethingTo(i)
    list2.append(temporaryVariable)
list1 = list2
```

Your second problem is the indexes, since you are using `[n]` at the end of the variable name, you are trying to call the `n`th item in the `response` list.

```
>>>x = [1,2,3]
>>>x[1]
2
>>>x[2] = "airplane"
>>>x[2]
'airplane'
```